# Is it posible to get Account Name from Quote in email template?

Tags: email-template, administration

There is a standard lookup on quote object to Account
[image]

But there is no such field in merge fields
[image]
How I can get this field in the email template ,without any customisation such as formula?

Comment: Cross object merge fields are problematic in standard classic email templates - but a VF email template can handle them without issue

Comment: It would, however, be far easier and lighter weight to simply add a cross-object formula field to get the Account Name into the Quote and then use that than creating a VF email template...

Comment: Vote for this idea: [Cross-object merge fields in an Email Template](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdifOUAR/cross-object-merge-fields-in-email-template). So far this is a top idea in [May 2022 prioritization cycle](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/prioritization), so hopefully it'll get implemented in the next year or ten. The voting cycle for May 22 prioritization has a little bit of time left, vote it up!

Comment: I simply cant get the id of account